# what is difference between document.body.ononline and navigator.onLine

Tags: javascript

what is difference between `document.body.ononline` and `navigator.onLine`? are they use same `Java Script` API to validate the network connect and disconnect (on/off)? I did `google` but did not find promising answer. If both the are having there own API to validate network connection then, which one is more reliable to use `document.body.ononline` or `navigator.onLine`

Comment: Did you read the MDN on it? Answers the question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NavigatorOnLine.onLine documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine.onLine) states that:

> Returns the online status of the browser. The property returns a
>   boolean value, with true for being online and false for being offline.
>   The property sends updates whenever the browser's ability to connect
>   to the network changes.

[ononline documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc304127%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) shows that it is an event, used when the browser goes online, eg:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.body.ononline = function() { alert('browser is now ONLINE'); };
}
```

Comment: correct, but both can be use to check the network connect/disconnect. I just wanted to know , which one is more reliable to use.

Comment: They are both equally reliable, it depends if you want to actively check yourself (use `.onLine`) or if you want to be notified when the browser goes online (use `.ononline`)

Comment: Your code should be `document.body.ononline = function() { ... };`. Even better would be `addEventListener('online', function () { ... });`.

Answer (score 1):

These **[document.body.online](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Online_and_offline_events)** events are fired on the  of each page when the browser switches between online mode.

The **[navigator.onLine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine.onLine)** property returns a Boolean value that specifies whether the system is in offline mode.

> The navigator.onLine property returns a boolean value, with true for being online and
>   false for being offline. The property sends updates whenever the
>   browser's ability to connect to the network changes. The update occurs
>   when the user follows links or when a script requests a remote page.
>   For example, the property should return false when users click links
>   soon after they lose internet connection.